# Git: Clone Missing in VS Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, clone

VSCode Version: 1.63

OS: Mac Monterey

I'm missing the option to clone repository. I have another Mac where it shows just fine.

**I checked settings and Git is missing under Extensions but I'm unsure how to get it back.**

[image: Explorer in VSCode]

Things I've tried:

- Shift+Ctrl+P Git:Clone (doesn't exist)
- Ensuring git and python are installed (they are)
- Verified that Github: Git Auth is enabled under Preferences (it is)
- Uninstalling/reinstalling (no change)
- Rebooted machine (no change)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are launching VSCode from a shell where git is recognized/installed, check first, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59121982/6309), it is not a license issue.

See "[`microsoft/vscode` issue 81287](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81287)":  xcodebuild license needs renewing.

---

The [OP AnaBee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18050700/anabee) reports making it work after a `git init`, and following "[Git missing in VS Code – No source control providers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60464541/6309)":

> Open Visual Studio Code, click left-bottom ⚙️ (gears) and select Command Palette.
>
> Search for the word "enable", and select Enable All Extensions.

Comment: When I try to execute `sudo xcodebuild -license` I get the message `xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance` 
I followed the steps in the same thread to no avail.

Comment: @AnaBee Since Git is missing under extension, do you see "There are no active source control providers", as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/46609255/6309"?

Comment: Yes. I have already tried:  `which git` to get my git path. Then updated the settings.json file. Still no luck. Actually in the settings file, that specific line is faded out when I go back to look at it. (not commented out; faded out. like inactive)

Comment: I got it to work!! I did the following:
`git init` and https://stackoverflow.com/a/60464541/18050700

Comment: @AnaBee Great! Well done, and good catch. I have edited the answer accordingly.